# Footnote in HTML Table

Tags: html

In the following HTML table snippet, I will like to add footnotes (or simple comments) for columns "stat 1", "stat 2" and "stat 3" to explain each of the stats in more detail. Preferably, want the comments/details to appear right below the table with each comment correctly referring to the right column. Any suggestion on how to achieve this? Thanks.

```
    if(!empty($output))
    {

        echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="imagetable">';
        echo '<caption>Table 1</caption>';
        echo '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Stat 1</th><th>Stat 2</th><th>Stat 3</th><th></tr>';

        foreach ($output as $result)
        {
            $temp = explode(" ",$result);
            echo '<tr>';
            for($i=0;$i<count($temp);$i++){
                echo '<td>',$temp[$i],'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table><br />';
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by “footnotes”? How are they related to the use of a table? How does this all relate to PHP? Exactly what should appear where? Can this be formulated just as an HTML question? Then please do so. If you, explain why.

Comment: It is a HTML question but, I showed the snippet that calls the HTML table. See my response to Jorge below on what I am looking for

Comment: No, edit the *question* to tell exactly what you mean and want. A question should be understandable as standalone, without peeking at comments and answers. And the comment does not answer any of the questions. You want something that is part of a table but is not part of a table?

Comment: Ok, modified the question with desire output expectation

Comment: You still haven’t described the desired rendering *or* functionality. How should comments “refer” to the right column, and should they be part of the table or not?

Comment: Table header should be like: Date | a(should be superscript)Stat 1 | b Stat 2. In the note (below the table) should be "a Note on Stat 1" "b Note on Stat 2"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tfoot` (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tfoot.asp)

```
if(!empty($output))
    {

        echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="imagetable">';
        echo '<caption>Table 1</caption>';
        echo '<thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Stat 1</th><th>Stat 2</th><th>Stat 3</th></tr></thead>';
        echo '<tfoot><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>*note 1</td><td>*note 2</td><td>*note 3</td></tr></tfoot>';

        foreach ($output as $result)
        {
            $temp = explode(" ",$result);
            echo '<tr>';
            for($i=0;$i<count($temp);$i++){
                echo '<td>',$temp[$i],'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table><br />';
    }
```

Comment: thanks but, I was looking to put the note at the bottom of the table and not as part of the last row. I also want a reference from the note to the column is refers to, like "1 note of columnX" and columnX will have a 1 next to it.